# How to read data from Geo-Replication Secondary database?

Tags: c#, azure-sql-database

I have an Azure SQL (S3) geo-replicated read-only database.
My problem is that when I query the Read-only from VisualStudio I can see the Query is hitting the Master database.
I expect the Query to hit the Read-only database.

But if I run the same Query from SMSM connected to Read-only then I can see the Read-only database is hit. This works as expected.

**To see the last Query in each database I use following SQL.**

SELECT execquery.last_execution_time AS [Date Time], execsql.text AS [Script] FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS execquery
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(execquery.sql_handle) AS execsql
ORDER BY execquery.last_execution_time DESC

**Question**

Why is my c# (entityframework 6.0) code not showing in the Read-only database?

**Background**

The goal is to have a read-only SQL to handle the external API load so the Master SQL is not to load.

In Azure Portal, I created a Geo-Replication SQL in the same region as Master.

The connection string is set to Read-only database.
I tried[ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly] flag in connectionstring with no success.

Comment: What connection string do you use in each case? What SSMS settings?  It's the *connection string* that specifies the database to hit, not the query. SSMS doesn't do anything differently, it's just another client application as far as Azure SQL is concerned

Comment: Make sure the connection string used by EF is what you think it is too. Perhaps you're using a connection that *doesn't* contain `ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly;`. Do you read the connection string directly from configuration or do you modify it afterwards?

Comment: Hi and Thanks.
I take the connectionstring from Azure Portal on Readonly database and add the "ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly;". In SSMS I cant see the connectionstring but I connect SSMS to the Server with Readonly database and make Query to it.  I tried alot of different Connectionstrings settings and Im almost sure I use the correct Connectionstrings in C#.

Comment: Im using SQL S3 on Master. Not the Premium SQL. I read old articles that I need a Premium SQL to make Quieries to Readonly replica? Can this be a problem? Do I need to Upgrade to Premium SQL?

Comment: I'll repeat it. SSMS is just a client tool. You still haven't posted your code. Start with a *simple* console application that uses only ADO.NET to connect to the replica - a single SqlConnection, a single SqlCommand. Instead of trying to find the last query, use what [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-read-scale-out) shows you should use to actually determine whether the database is updatable: `SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX(DB_NAME(), 'Updateability')`, with `SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar`.

Comment: Thanks! 
I think I solved the problem.You was correct. Connectionstring was the issue. To get correct connectionstring I used "Cloud Explorer" and "Server Explorer" in VS to connect to Azure Readonly SQL. Then I can see full Connectionstring in VS. I copied this and it works. Small differences from my old connectionstring.

Comment: After that, add EF to that console application and execute the same raw SQL command. Did something change? If not, you know it's not EF at fault. If *yes*, even though you explicitly used `ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly;` in the one and only connection string, you'll know something is really happening

Comment: connectionString="Data Source=readonlyserver.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=database;User ID=user;Password=xxxxx;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False" - This connectionstring works for me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was old format on the connectionstring "User ID".
I used "username@server". The @server was pointing to the server of Master Sql.
I changed to only "username" and now it works.